# React: Syntax for calling setState in Switch Return

Tags: reactjs

Having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong here.. and I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Just trying to increment counters on state whenever the data passed into this switch call matches each category, but for some reason the counter doesn't increment...

```
countCategories(cart) {
cart.map(function(item){
  switch (item.type) {
      case "beverage": return () => { this.setState({
        countBeverage: this.state.countBeverage + 1
      }); }
      case "fruit": return () => { this.setState({
        countFruit: this.state.countFruit + 1
      }); }
      case "vegetable": return () => { this.setState({
        countVegetable: this.state.countVegetable + 1
      }); }
      case "snack": return () => { this.setState({
        countSnack: this.state.countSnack + 1
      }); }
      default: return console.log("unknown category");
    };
}); }
```

I also tried it this way, but I don't think I have a reference to 'this' when I call it this way:

```
countCategories(cart) {
cart.map(function(item){
  switch (item.type) {
      case "beverage": return this.setState({
        countBeverage: this.state.countBeverage + 1
      })
      case "fruit": return this.setState({
        countFruit: this.state.countFruit + 1
      })
      case "vegetable": return this.setState({
        countVegetable: this.state.countVegetable + 1
      })
      case "snack": return this.setState({
        countSnack: this.state.countSnack + 1
      });
      default: return console.log("unknown category");
    };
}); }
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: When is `countCategories` called?

Comment: first calculate the value, then set it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this dude:

```
let food = [{type: "snack"},{type: "snack"},{type: "snack"},{type: "snack"}, 
            {type: "veggi"},{type: "veggi"},{type: "veggi"},{type: "veggi"}]

let foodCount = {
   veggiCount: this.state.veggiCount || 0, 
   snackCount: this.state.snackCount || 0,
   beefCount:  this.state.beefCount || 0,
   fruitCount: this.state.fruitCount || 0
};

food.map(item => foodCount[item + "Count"]++ )
this.setState(foodCount)
```

The important thing here, is to setState 1. once, 2. when the calculation has completed. Avoid setting the state in loops or iterations like `for(...) setState()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're invoking `countCategories` bound to the component (the value of `this` is the component), in your first code, which should work, you could change the mapping function to an arrow function, so it keeps the `this` value of the `countCategories` function. Another weird thing I've noticed is that you're creating an array of functions by returning functions that should change the state, instead of actually changing the state:

```
countCategories(cart) {
  // Notice the change in the next line
  cart.map(item => {
    switch (item.type) {
      case "beverage": 
        // Set the state instead of returning a function that sets the state
        this.setState({
          countBeverage: this.state.countBeverage + 1
        });
        break;
      case "fruit": 
        this.setState({
          countFruit: this.state.countFruit + 1
        });
        break;
      case "vegetable": 
        this.setState({
          countVegetable: this.state.countVegetable + 1
        });
        break;
      case "snack": 
        this.setState({
          countSnack: this.state.countSnack + 1
        });
        break;
      default: 
        console.log("unknown category");
        break;
    };
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An important consideration here is that `setState` is asynchronous so you can't read the value in the same execution cycle and increment it. Instead, I'd suggest creating a set of changes and then apply them in a single `setState`.

Below I've used `map` to iterate over the cart and and increment the state values stored in a cloned copy of state (because `this.state` should be considered immutable). Then once complete, the state is updated.

```
let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
cart.map((item) => {
  // adapt type to state string -> snack to countSnack
  const type = item.type.replace(/^(.)/, (s) => 'count' + s.toUpperCase());
  newState[type] = (newState[type] || 0) + 1;
});

this.setState(newState);
```

See notes within [Component API documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) for details