# react count object properties in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am fetching data by an API. It is a movie, tv show, person database. When I search a word in the search box, it returns the related movie, tv show and person names in objects nested in an array. for example when I search "fight":

```
    [
    0:{original_name: "쌈 마이웨이", id: 70813, media_type: "tv", name: "Fight My Way", vote_count: 5,…}

    1:{vote_average: 8.2, vote_count: 8057, id: 550, video: false, media_type: "movie", title: "Fight Club",…}

    2:{vote_average: 6.1, vote_count: 215, id: 345922, video: false, media_type: "movie",…}

    3:{original_name: "Fight", id: 46554, media_type: "tv", name: "Fight", vote_count: 0, vote_average: 0,…}

    4:{original_name: "The Good Fight", id: 69158, media_type: "tv", name: "The Good Fight", vote_count: 22,…}

    5:{vote_average: 0, vote_count: 0, id: 158301, video: false, media_type: "movie", title: "Fight",…}
   ]
```

there are more results but I cut them. As you can see there are `media_type` properties in each object. there are 3 media types as you can understand (movie, tv, person). I want to count each type.

actually; I want the same thing in the link I guess: [React: Syntax for calling setState in Switch Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856852/react-syntax-for-calling-setstate-in-switch-return)

but it doesn't work for me. I tried to change simply the state of movieCount to 3 like this:

```
countType() {
        this.props.movies.map(movie => {
            return() => {
            if(movie.media_type === 'movie') {
                this.setState({ movieCount: 3});
                console.log(this.state);
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

but it doesn't work too.and I researched on the internet this stuff in javascript documentation and forums. not about just react. but I couldn't do anything. I know it's simple.

so how can I count objects in an array according to their property types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok i found the solition. thank you to poohitan for answer. i solved it 
through his answer.

```
countType(type) {
        const countTypes = this.props.movies.filter(movie => movie.media_type === type);
        return countTypes.length;
    }
```

and while i am rendering my tv results, i just call the method above with type. for example:

```
return ( 
    <div> 
      movie count: {this.countType('movie')} 
      tv show count: {this.countType('tv')} 
    </div> 
    );
```

Comment: It breaks once props get updated. "this.props.movies.filter is not a function". Any idea how to get around it ?

Comment: How did you exactly call the function? It seems that you miss binding or you didn't pass props correctly. (Maybe wrote props name wrong)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that the data you fetched from API is stored in `data` variable, you can try the following code to find the count of `movie` media type in your data array:

```
const movies = data.filter(item => item.media_type === 'movie'));
const moviesCount = movies.length;
```

You can also dynamically calculate count of every `media_type` in your data array:

```
const mediaTypes = data
    .map(dataItem => dataItem.media_type) // get all media types
    .filter((mediaType, index, array) => array.indexOf(mediaType) === index); // filter out duplicates
  
const counts = mediaTypes
  .map(mediaType => ({
    type: mediaType,
    count: data.filter(item => item.media_type === mediaType).length
  }));
```

Then `counts` will be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "tv",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "movie",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: in this code, is data paramater my movies array? so dont i need map function?

Comment: Yes, `data` is the array which you posted in the question. I've edited the answer.

Comment: thanks man. i just solve it like:

        const countTypes = this.props.movies.filter(movie => movie.media_type === type);
        const movieCounted = countTypes.length;

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    { original_name: "쌈 마이웨이", id: 70813, media_type: "tv", name: "Fight My Way", vote_count: 5 },

    { vote_average: 8.2, vote_count: 8057, id: 550, video: false, media_type: "movie", title: "Fight Club" },

    { vote_average: 6.1, vote_count: 215, id: 345922, video: false, media_type: "movie" },

    { original_name: "Fight", id: 46554, media_type: "tv", name: "Fight", vote_count: 0, vote_average: 0 },

    { original_name: "The Good Fight", id: 69158, media_type: "tv", name: "The Good Fight", vote_count: 22 },

    { vote_average: 0, vote_count: 0, id: 158301, video: false, media_type: "movie", title: "Fight" },
]

this.types = {};

data.forEach((d) => {
    if (!this.types[d["media_type"]]) {
        this.types[d["media_type"]] = 1;
    } else {
        this.types[d["media_type"]] += 1;
    }
})

console.log(this.types);
// you will get answer { tv: 3, movie: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way:

```
render()  {
    let countTypes = ' '
         return ({
             list.length > 0
                 ?
                  <span> {countTypes = (list.filter(moviesFilter => 
                  moviesFilter.type.id === this.props.typeId)).length} 
                  </span>
                :
                  <DisplayMessage message="0" />
        })
}
```